# android change UI from background thread - why it's working?

Tags: android, view, background-process

Will an application ever crash when changing text, background resource and inflating some views in it in a background thread, if the view's visibility is *GONE*? I've done some tests with two buttons, one *visible* and one *gone*, and when I changed text of the *visible* one in a background thread, it crashed, and when I changed the text of the button with the *GONE* visibility, it worked without a crash. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I have a something for you.

**Event Handling and Threading**

The basic cycle of a view is as follows:

1. An event comes in and is dispatched to the appropriate view. The
   view handles the event and notifies any listeners.
2. If in the course of processing the event, the view's bounds may need
   to be changed, the view will call `requestLayout()`.
3. Similarly, if in the course of processing the event the view's
   appearance may need to be changed, the view will call `invalidate()`.
4. If either `requestLayout()` or `invalidate()` were called, the framework
   will take care of measuring, laying out, and drawing the tree as
   appropriate.

**Note:** The entire view tree is single threaded. You must always be on the UI thread when calling any method on any view. If you are doing work on other threads and want to update the state of a view from that thread, you should use a Handler.

You can find much more here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html .

In your case Your View is already GONE so I think its not attached to View Tree.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info or I missed something.

Comment: This would explain why changing text of a button with GONE visibility from another thread didn't crashed... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an Handler!
In that handler put your code to update your UI and in the thread call the Handler!
You should never update the UI from an thread directly in none of langages! it's a big error in programming!

Example to create your handler:

```
static Handler updater1 = new Handler() {
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   //your code to update the UI
   }
};
```

Example to call your handler from the thread:

```
updater1.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

The behaviors about to change the text from a thread can be different in all langages! but you should never do that it's a big error!
Maybe when you tried to update a text on a button with visibility "GONE" it just not worked! but you can't see it!

Comment: ok but I need to know why it's working on button with GONE visibility ?

Comment: You haven't answered the question.